# Sencha Touch 2 - Ext.device.SQLite.Database working?

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone have an example of use of the class Ext.device.SQLite.Database?

Can anyone provide a code for it?

I'm trying to implement SQLite on ST2 and build app native over Android 4. When I use websql, the app didn't run, apperars just three circles blinking and nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the proxy in webapps is fairly simple – just switch the proxy on the model definition like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Model', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Sql'],

config: {

    identifier: {
        type: 'uuid'
    },

    fields: [
        ...
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'sql'
    }
}});
```

The only other thing worth noting is that, because you are using a database, all your save and load calls will be asynchronous. Unlike localstorage, which saves and loads instantly, you will need to rely on Sencha Touch’s callbacks and listeners. Load on both models and stores have a callback, and save on a model has a callback

Comment: If you're going to provide an answer that is directly copied-and-pasted from another website, at least provide your source: http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/tag/sencha-touch-sqlite/